# Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `error`

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I am trying to write component and its stories in storybook for react, but now and then I am getting this error message:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFXfV.png]

Here is the code in the component. I have noticed that if I removed `{...props}` from input element the message is gone, but i need it to pass more props that i need. Why I am getting this error ?

```
import React from 'react'
import './Input.css';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Input = (props) => {
  const { error, validated, className, handleChange } = props;

    return (
      <div className="input-group mb-3">
        <input
          className={`form-control ${className} ${
            error ? 'is-invalid' : ''
          } ${validated ? 'is-valid' : ''}`}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value)}
          {...props}
        />
      </div>
    );
}

export default Input;

Input.propTypes = {
  error: PropTypes.bool,
  validated: PropTypes.bool,
  morestyles: PropTypes.string,
  handleChange:PropTypes.func
};
```

Here is the code in the story:

```
export const Error = (args) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  return (
    <Input
    value={value}
    onChange={(...params) => {
      args.handleChange(...params);
      setValue(...params);
    }}
    type="text"
    placeholder="Bad value"
    name="Voornaam"
    error={true}
    {...args}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: not sure if the props are getting converted to a string, may be try adding '+' before checking +error ? 'is-invalid' : ''

Comment: thanks, but it didn't  work in my case. Here i found  the solution : https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs#why-am-i-getting-html-attribute-warnings

Answer (score 2):

Manage to fix it by replacing :

```
const Input = (props) => {
  const { error, validated, className, handleChange } = props;

the rest is the same
}
```

with :

```
const Input = ({error, validated, morestyles, handleChange, ...props}) => { the rest is the same
}
```

Comment: Somehow, this is working :)